# How can I allow the child process to create nested user namespace?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I use the following code to create a child process in a new user namespace:

```
pid_t child = syscall (SYS_clone, SIGCHLD | CLONE_NEWNS | CLONE_NEWUSER, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In the parent process, I write the `uid_map` and `gid_map` and map the current uid and pid to itself.

In the child process I will call `execvp` to start a new process, and that process may call `unshare` with `CLONE_NEWUSER` flag, which operation is not permitted in the new user namespace.

My question is, is it possible to permit the `unshare` operation to the process started by `execvp`?

I followed the example in the man page of `user_namespace` and use `pipe` to ensure the `uid_map` and `gid_map` is written before `execvp` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your mappings are somehow incorrect. From `man 2 unshare`, it looks like you're hitting this:

```
       EPERM  CLONE_NEWUSER was specified in flags, but either  the  effective
              user  ID or the effective group ID of the caller does not have a
              mapping in the parent namespace (see user_namespaces(7)).
```